# How do I add Gmail API library to my Maven project in IntelliJ?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, gmail-api

It seems like I'm not able to add the correct dependency to my Maven project in IntelliJ.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev20210614-1.31.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the dependency I've added in my pom.xml file, but IntelliJ just marks the words red and says : **Dependency 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev20210614-1.31.0' not found**.

I've searched for jar files to download and manually add to the dependencies in project structure, but I can't seem to find one.

Could you please help me and tell me what I'doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The version you are referring to does not exists:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-gmail -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
    <version>v1-rev110-1.25.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Look at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-gmail for available releeases.

Answer (score 0):

It's the wrong version. Maybe it's not yet public on maven. But you can add to **`pom.xml`** normally follow URL:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/tree/master/clients/google-api-services-gmail/v1/1.31.0

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
  <version>v1-rev20210614-1.32.1</version>
</dependency>
```